# cannot solve "Array to string conversion in .."

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-blade

I'm trying to output the names out of an array

when I output them as a `{!! !!}` i get the following error "Array to string conversion in .." but with a `@dump` i get the following data:

`array(2){[0]=> object(stdClass)#7052(1){["data"] => string(5)"data1"} [1]=> object(stdClass)#7049(1){["data"] =>string(5)"data2"}}`

I've already tried:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
{!! $item !!}
@endforeach
```

but this did not solve the ploblem

I'm using php blade to solve this problem

Comment: try $item['data']

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to view an array in string format is to do this

```
{!! json_encode($item) !!}
```

Then more likely your final answer will be something like this.

```
{!! $item['my_key_name'] !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is items[0] = data['data1','data2']
so when you use foreach($items as $item), $item returns value data so you need 2nd loop to extract the data or you need to use

```
@foreach($items[0] as $item)
{!! $item !!}
@endforeach
```